# accessing method in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to fetch phone number from XML and to use it for sending sms (It works).

Let, the Method which Loads phone number:

```
public string LoadPhoneNumber(string phoneNum)
    {        
         XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/AppUsers/Users.xml");
            var items = from item in xmlDoc.Elements("Users").Elements("user")
                        where item != null &&(item.Attribute("author").Value == "Home Owner")

                        select item;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {                  
                  phoneNum=item.Element("mobile").Value.ToString();      

            }
            return phoneNum;
    }
```

The Problem:
I tried to use the phone number from the method return.

```
string phoneNum;
sms.sendMsg(port, LoadPhoneNumber(phoneNUm), "Unknown Intruder is detected!)
```

Comment: "cannot work" doesn't tell us *anything* about what problem you're seeing. (Note that currently you're only returning the *last* matching phone number, by the way - there are much cleaner ways to write that query...)

Comment: Good, can you show me the cleaner way?

Comment: Well that's not really part of your question at the moment - if you can make it clear what's actually going wrong, so that I can write a useful answer, I'll include a better query there. (But what do you want to do if there *are* multiple home owner values? Do you definitely want the last? Why not the first?)

Comment: Very useful question. I have only one Home Owner permitted to register in my database.

Comment: @ensberiyu From what you say `The Problem: I tried to use the phone number from the method return.` I wonder if you are triying to use a string where it is supposed to use an integer number.

Comment: you are correct, but the the sms sending class uses string for the phone number. B/C it adds "+001" like this.

Comment: I was just trying to help you to make your question clear. As it is now, we cannot help you. I suggest you to explain what's wrong (an exception, just a unexpected result...) and add anny detail you think we need (if an exception, copy the stack trace, if unexpected result, what do you get and what do you expect). Maybe also a small part of your xml and the needed part of you sms class.

Comment: You are only returning a single string and your linq is returning multiple items.  Use FirstOrDefault to get first results from query.

Comment: @jdweng: While I agree that `FirstOrDefault` would be a better way of returning the first value from the query, I don't think that's the problem the OP is asking about - unfortunately, the OP hasn't made it clear what they *are* asking about...

Comment: Jon : The method returns a 'string'.  The should describe what the OP is asking.

Comment: Well, Now I have got the solution. @Blas

Comment: @ensberiyu Then, if you think more people could meet a similar problem, you could write your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string LoadPhoneNumber()
    {        
         XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/AppUsers/Users.xml");
            var items = from item in xmlDoc.Elements("Users").Elements("user")
                        where item != null &&(item.Attribute("author").Value == "Home Owner")

                        select item;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {                  
                  string phoneNum=item.Element("mobile").Value.ToString();
                  return PhoneNum;      

            }
            return LoadPhoneNumber();
    }
```